# My control keys shortcut has been swapped

Tags: kali-linux, keyboard-shortcuts

from what I have observed, these are the keys that suddenly acting weird:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>

These don't work using left control but when using right control It works.

I don't really recall why but I have'nt installed or updated my OS,
It just happens while I'm doing a project in `nvim` inside `tmux` then suddenly neovim froze so I just killed the process.

Output from `xev`:

Pressing Left control:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x119, subw 0x0, time 3929597, (466,326), root:(503,432),
    state 0x14, keycode 37 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x119, subw 0x0, time 3943294, (194,609), root:(231,715),
    state 0x10, keycode 49 (keysym 0x60, grave), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (60) "`"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (60) "`"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Pressing right control:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x119, subw 0x0, time 4004542, (259,372), root:(296,478),
    state 0x14, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2200001,
    root 0x119, subw 0x0, time 4005270, (259,372), root:(296,478),
    state 0x10, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes:
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```